# Variable does not exist: sObjectType (Task.sObjectType)

Tags: apex

Calling `_____.sObjectType` works on everything else, why does `Task.sObjectType` not work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must have a class or local variable named `Task`. Any time you get this sort of name shadowing, you can work around it by referencing `Schema.Task.sObjectType` instead, though you should avoid it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! I will never get used to Apex being case insensitive. In my case, the `Account` name was shadowed by a variable `account`. Calling an instance of a class the same as the class name but starting with a lower case letter is absolutely normal in Java, and because of case sensitivity `Account` and `account` are completely different identifiers. But not in Apex. So I need to spend energy coming up with names for my instances like `anAccount` or `myAccount`. Silliness.

Comment: Generally you can just use `record` and `records`.

Comment: Like `accountRecord`? I guess that works, just a bit more typing, which we know programmers like to avoid :)

Comment: No I mean often there is only one type of SObject relevant to a context and therefore `record` is a perfectly acceptable variable name all on its own.